# XSLT for Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint

Why should we use XSLT to web parts?

Can anyone please route me to good resources for learning XSLT to web parts.

I think you might have understood by my Question. I am a starter.

Cheers!
Grace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSLT Give good Flexibility. As most of the Web Parts UI has been done at the Development level.Having XSLT will allow you to change the look and feel of the Web Part at any time you want. Once Good Example is [Content Query Web Part](http://blogs.msdn.com/ecm/archive/2006/10/25/configuring-and-customizing-the-content-query-web-part.aspx). Good place to start XSLT is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).

Answer (score 2):

And it promoties reusability. (i.e. multiple different webpart using the same layout xsl file, which can be Linked to a WebPart using the XslLink tag).